# .Net how to play audio in the root of the website with System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer()

Tags: c#

I use this code blow in .NET. It works fine. The problem is that I want this audio to play in the root of the website. What changes should I make for this? Thanks

```
var sample= new System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer();
sample.Open(new System.Uri( @"D:\voices\1.wav");
sample.Play();
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. You should add code examples and the exact errors you received, it might help users who try to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a web application, this ***might*** look something like this:

```
sample.Open(new System.Uri(Server.MapPath("~/") + @"\voices\1.wav");
```

I say ***might*** because that all depends on whether or not the `voices` folder exists in the root of the website. Additionally, you should probably leverage `Path.Combine` instead:

```
var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/"), "voices", "1.wav");
sample.Open(path);
```

Finally, I don't know what `sample` is, but the `Open` method may not work in a website. I'm making the assumption you know what `Open` does and whether or not it can work in a website.

Comment: I don't get any errors but the audio doesn't play.

Comment: @user2569038, and that's something I expected fully. Again, I didn't know what `sample` was, nor did I know what `Open` was supposed to do. If this is an audio file you want to play you're going to need to look at some different options. You can use a JavaScript player, like the free Yahoo one or you can use the HTML `<audio>` tag if your users are going to be using compliant browsers. One additional option is to have the user download the file and play it. Either way, you need to get this file to the client. Clearly the client isn't going to be able to hear the audio playing on the server.

Comment: I apologize to you, it works. I made a mistake that's why this did not work at the beginning. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Use `server.mappath("~/")` <- that's the filesystem root for your website.

```
dim path as string = server.mappath("~/") & "/voices/1.wav"
```

Note that backslashes, for filesystem path, not URI.

Hope it helps.